# Properties of $S\subset C[0,1]$ (nonempty, closed, convex, no element in the least norm).

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

In $C[0,1]$ consider the set $S$ of functions $f$ such that
$$\int_0^{1/2}f(t)dt - \int_{1/2}^{1}f(t)dt = 1$$

Prove the following:

1) $S$ is nonempty

2) $S$ is closed

3) $S$ is convex

4) $f$ does not posses an element with the least norm.

So for (1) I set $f(t)=1-4t$, so
$$\int_0^{1/2}(1-4t)dt - \int_{1/2}^{1}(1-4t)dt = 1$$

Therefore $S$ is nonempty.

**Based on the hint below**

Let $f,g\in C[0,1]$ be given. Then:

$$\Lambda(\alpha f + \beta g)=\int_0^{1/2}\alpha f + \beta gdt - \int_{1/2}^{1}\alpha f + \beta gdt = 1$$
$$=\int_0^{1/2}\alpha fdt + \int_0^{1/2} \beta gdt - \int_{1/2}^{1}\alpha fdt - \int_{1/2}^{1} \beta gdt = 1$$
$$=\int_0^{1/2}\alpha fdt - \int_{1/2}^{1}\alpha fdt + \int_0^{1/2} \beta gdt - \int_{1/2}^{1} \beta gdt = 1$$
$$=\alpha (\int_0^{1/2} fdt - \int_{1/2}^{1} fdt) + \beta (\int_0^{1/2} gdt - \int_{1/2}^{1} gdt) = 1$$
$$=\alpha (\Lambda(f)) + \beta (\Lambda(g)) = 1$$

So $\Lambda$ is a linear functional.

I am stuck on (2), how I would show that $S$ is closed (I have not started 3 or 4 yet, as I am stuck on 2).

Comment: Note that $S = \Lambda^{-1}(\{1\})$. Some properties of continuous maps resp. of linear maps immediately tell you that 2) and 3) hold. Which?

Comment: So we know that any set of only one point is closed.
We also know that $f:X\to Y$ is continuous if:

$f^{-1}(A)$ is a closed subset of $X$ for every closed subset $A \subset Y$

As $Y = {1}$, $A={1} \subset Y$ and $A$ is closed, as is $\Lambda^{-1}({1})$ therefore $\Lambda$ is continuous.

Would that be correct?

Comment: Show the continuity by finding $\lVert\Lambda\rVert$. Then the closedness of $S$ follows since $\{1\}\subset\mathbb{R}$ is closed.

Comment: We haven't learned about $||\Lambda||$... so I am not sure how I would find that..

Comment: No $$\lVert\Lambda\rVert = \inf \left\{ C > 0 : (\forall f)\bigl(\lvert\Lambda(f)\rvert \leqslant C\cdot\lVert f\rVert\bigr)\right\}$$ or $$\lVert \Lambda \rVert = \sup_{\lVert f\rVert \leqslant 1} \lvert\Lambda(f)\rvert\,?$$ (These are equivalent, of course.)

Comment: So since $\Lambda \colon f \mapsto \int_0^{1/2} f(t)\,dt - \int_{1/2}^1 f(t)\,dt = 1$, then $||\Lambda || = sup|\Lambda (f)| = 1$?

Comment: No, $\Lambda\colon f\mapsto\int_0^{1/2} f(t)\,dt - \int_{1/2}^1 f(t)\,dt=1$ makes no sense, to find $\lVert\Lambda\rVert$, forget about $S$. You have $$\lvert \Lambda(f)\rvert = \left\lvert \int_0^{1/2} f(t)\,dt - \int_{1/2}^1 f(t)\,dt\right\rvert \leqslant \left\lvert \int_0^{1/2} f(t)\,dt\right\rvert + \left\lvert \int_{1/2}^1 f(t)\,dt\right\rvert \leqslant \int_0^{1/2} \lvert f(t)\rvert\,dt + \int_{1/2}^1\lvert f(t)\rvert\,dt,$$ and that is $\int_0^1\lvert f(t)\rvert\,dt \leqslant (1-0)\cdot \sup \{ \lvert f(t)\rvert : t\in [0,1]\} = \lVert f\rVert$, whence $\lVert\Lambda\rVert\leqslant 1$.

Comment: Now you need to see that you can come arbitrarily close to that to see that indeed $\lVert\Lambda\rVert = 1$.

Comment: I am confused though... $\| \Lambda \|$ does not appear to be part of that inequality...

So would you use $\lVert\Lambda\rVert = \inf \left\{ C > 0 : (\forall f)\bigl(\lvert\Lambda(f)\rvert \leqslant C\cdot\lVert f\rVert\bigr)\right\}$, since you have shown that $|\Lambda (f)| \leq \| f \| \implies |\Lambda (f)| \leq C*\| f \|, C>0$ ?

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you use $\lVert\Lambda\rVert = \inf \{C > 0 : \lvert\Lambda(f)\rvert\leqslant C\lVert f\rVert\}$ or $\lVert\Lambda\rVert = \sup\limits_{\lVert f\rVert \leqslant 1} \lvert\Lambda(f)\rvert$. The inequality $\lvert\Lambda(f)\rvert \leqslant \lVert f\rVert$ shows that $C = 1$ appears in the set on the right of the first, as well as that the supremum in the second is $\leqslant 1$. So either way, we have $\lVert\Lambda\rVert\leqslant 1$. To see $\lVert\Lambda\rVert = 1$, I think using the supremum is a little easier.

Comment: So then... since $|\Lambda (f)|\leq 1$ then for any $\epsilon >0$ then there exists $f_n$ such that $|sup|\Lambda (f_n)| - 1|\leq\epsilon$?

Answer (score 4):

Consider the map

$$\Lambda \colon f \mapsto \int_0^{1/2} f(t)\,dt - \int_{1/2}^1 f(t)\,dt.$$

Show that $\Lambda \colon C[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous linear map.

We have

\begin{align}
\lvert \Lambda (f)\rVert &= \left\lvert \int_0^{1/2} f(t)\,dt - \int_{1/2}^1 f(t)\,dt\right\rvert\\
&\leqslant \int_0^{1/2} \lvert f(t)\rvert\,dt + \int_{1/2}^1\lvert f(t)\rvert\,dt\\
&= \int_0^1 \lvert f(t)\rvert\,dt\\
&\leqslant \int_0^1 \lVert f\rVert\,dt\\
&= \lVert f\rVert.
\end{align}

So $\lvert \Lambda(f) - \Lambda(g)\rvert \leqslant \lVert f-g\rVert$ by linearity, and that means that $\Lambda$ is (Lipschitz-)continuous (with Lipschitz constant $1$).

Use the continuity of $\Lambda$ to deduce 2), and the linearity for 3). Compute $\lVert\Lambda\rVert$ to find a lower bound for the norms of elements of $S$, show that the bound you obtain from $\lVert\Lambda\rVert$ is the largest lower bound, but that it is not attained.

Since $\{1\}$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$ (or $\mathbb{C}$ if complex functions are considered), and $\Lambda$ is continuous, the closedness of $S = \Lambda^{-1}(\{1\})$ follows.

Since $\{1\}$ is convex, and $\Lambda$ linear, the convexity of $S$ follows, because the images and preimages of convex sets under linear maps are again convex.

Above we saw that

$$\lVert\Lambda \rVert := \sup_{\lVert f\rVert = 1} \lvert \Lambda(f)\rvert \leqslant 1,$$

and the functions

$$f_n(t) = \begin{cases}\qquad 1 &, 0 \leqslant t \leqslant \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{n} \\ - n\left(t-\frac{1}{2}\right) &, \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{n} < t < \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{n} \\ \quad\;\; -1 &, \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{n} \leqslant t \leqslant 1\end{cases}$$

yield

$$\Lambda(f_n) = 2\left(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{n}\right) + 2\cdot\frac{1}{2}\cdot 1 \cdot \frac{1}{n} = 1 - \frac{1}{n}$$

for $n \geqslant 2$, so, since $\lVert f_n\rVert = 1$, $\lVert\Lambda\rVert = 1$ follows. From that, we deduce

$$\lVert f\rVert \geqslant 1$$

for all $f\in S$, and the functions $g_n = \frac{n}{n-1}f_n$ show that

$$\inf \left\{ \lvert f\rVert : f \in S\right\} = 1.$$

It remains to be seen that the infimum is not attained.

So let $f \in C([0,1])$ with $\lVert f\rVert \leqslant 1$. We have to show that then $\Lambda(f)\neq 1$.

If $f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \leqslant \frac{1}{2}$, the continuity of $f$ implies that there is a $\delta \in \left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right)$ with $f(t) \leqslant \frac{3}{4}$ for $t \in \left[\frac{1}{2}-\delta,\frac{1}{2}\right]$. Then

\begin{align}
\Lambda(f) &= \int_0^{1/2-\delta} f(t)\,dt + \int_{1/2-\delta}^{1/2} f(t)\,dt - \int_{1/2}^1 f(t)\,dt\\
&\leqslant \left(\frac{1}{2}-\delta\right)\cdot 1 + \delta\cdot \frac{3}{4} + \frac{1}{2}\cdot 1\\
&= 1 - \frac{\delta}{4}\\
&< 1.
\end{align}

Similarly, we see that $\Lambda(f) < 1$ if $f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \geqslant -\frac{1}{2}$. Since one of the two conditions must be satisfied, it follows that $\Lambda(f) < 1$ for all $f\in C([0,1])$ with $\lVert f\rVert \leqslant 1$, hence $\lVert f\rVert > 1$ for all $f\in S$, i.e. the infimum of $\{ \lVert f\rVert : f\in S\}$ is not attained.

Comment: Using your hint, I updated the question for part (2). I believe I correctly showed that $\Lambda$ is a linear functional... but I always seem to get confused how to show something is continuous. I know with a Linear Functional that $\Lambda$ is continuous $\iff \Lambda$ is continuous at $0 \iff \Lambda$ is bounded... but I'm not sure how I would actually show that.

Comment: Boundedness: $\lvert \Lambda(f)\rvert \leqslant C\cdot \lVert f\rVert$ is the best way here.

Comment: So how does bounded and continuous show closedness?

Comment: Do you know a characterisation of continuous maps that uses closed sets?

Comment: So I got the continuous, and the convex... and I am working on the "No element of least norm". How do I know that there is no $f\in S$ such that $sup(|f(t)| : t\in [0,1])=1$?

Comment: Let $g\colon [0,1] \to\mathbb{R}$ be a measurable function such that $\sup \{ \lvert g(t)\rvert : t\in [0,1]\} \leqslant 1$, and $$\int_0^{1/2} g(t)\,dt - \int_{1/2}^1 g(t)\,dt = 1.$$ You need to see that such a $g$ cannot be continuous.

Comment: I struggle to understand why $\inf\{||f|| : f\in C\}=1$, can you please explain it in more details?